# Can we create push notification for Flutter iOS application when app is terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, mobile-application

I am developing one application using Flutter and our main targetted platform is iOS.

Here, we are implementing notification features using FCM Data messages. We can get notifications while app is in background or foreground but we can't get notification while app is terminated.

We are subscribing to one topic and messages are publishing on that topic.

So, Can anyone help me that how can we implement it in flutter or in swift iOS Native and use it in Flutter?

I tried to use **awesome_notification**, **flutter_local_notification** but it's not working in iOS.

If anyone did it with Swift iOS Native using Method channel, then it can be helpful.

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

**awesome_notification** and **flutter_local_notification** runs in flutter environment. Once the app is closed, they will also be killed.

If you are using FCM, you should get the Push Notification by default even if the app is terminated.

Comment: I am using the FCM but I am using FCM data message instead of FCM Notification Message, so any clue for that?